# Postfix/ClamAV not stopping viruses under Virtualmin

Tags: postfix, clamav, eicar-test-string

I am using Virtualmin and have it set up to have Postfix scan incoming emails with ClamAV (using `clamdscan`) and delete any emails which contain a virus. However when I email myself the EICAR test string, it comes through just fine. I know ClamAV will report this file as a virus. How can I troubleshoot this / what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check `/var/log/mail.log` and ensure the mail flow does go through clam, the mail headers are usually tagged as well.

Another thing to check is that it's clam 0.95 or newer, and `freshclam` is running to get virus defs, older versions of clam are now blocked due to limits.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what was wrong... but after many postfix and clamd server restarts, it's now working...